# AD users are unable to log into web server on Yosemite server

Tags: macos, webserver, active-directory

Active Directory Domain accounts unable to access the web server hosted on the Yosemite server. Local users can authenticate. I cannot find a setting to enable the Web services. I feel there is a setting to enable the website to recognize the AD users or AD user groups or Local groups with AD users.

The Yosemite is joined to the AD domain and the domain users/groups are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this question goes unanswered so far…..
However just updated my Server app to 5.0.3 and vow the domain users can authenticate to the web server hosted on Yosemite 10.10.5.

I will try to check what has changed…but as now it works. Really needed this functionality.

thanks